# Question about concurrently handling write and readonly access to file

Tags: c#

In a web application, is there a widely accepted way for handling locked files?

For example, a user has write access to a file so what would be the best way to let all other users access the file but with read only rights only.

Furthermore, if that user closes the file and all handles/resources are then disposed of, how can I decide who could have full write access to the file next?

This is assuming 1 user with full write access, and 10 users then with read-only access.

Also assuming a file link on a web application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the common approach is to protect the resource (file in your case) with ReaderWriterLock (there is ReaderWriterLockSlim in 3.5 that has better performance). To change the state (i.e. write/open-close/delete) you have to obtain Writer lock that could be granted only to one thread a time, and read operations need Reader lock, that may be shared between number of readers.